# Binary to String - Error on large numbers .StringIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, binary

I am doing some online coding projects trying to learn to program and advanced my skills.  The object of the current project is to figure out in binary which base 2 number matches with the other number first.  Im probably not explaining that correctly.

For example, if I had my binary strings as 10010 and 10011 the answer would be 2 but if I had 11111 and 10000, the answer would be 16.  My code below works for the first 4 tests it runs, but on the fifth test, it throws a .StringIndexOutOfBounds - the sample data on the last test being passed to my method is n = 1073741824 & m = 1006895103.  Im assuming it may be an issue regarding size or limitations of charAt() but not quite sure... any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Code Below:

```
int equalPairOfBits(int n, int m) {
        String theN = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
        String theM = Integer.toBinaryString(m);
        int pos = 0;
        int nLen = theN.length();
        int mLen = theN.length();
        char[] nArray = new char[nLen];
        char[] mArray = new char[mLen];

        for(int i = nLen - 1; i > -1; i--){
            nArray[i] = theN.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i = mLen - 1; i > -1; i--){
            mArray[i] = theM.charAt(i);
        }
        boolean isSame = false;
        for(int i = nLen - 1; i > -1; i--){
                if(nArray[i] == mArray[i] && isSame == false)
                {
                    pos = i;
                    isSame = true;
                }

        }
        pos = nLen - pos;
        int mult = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++){
            if(pos == 0)
                mult = 1;
            else
                mult = mult * 2; 
        }
        return mult;
    }
```

The Error I Am Getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at myCode._invoke(file.java on line ?)
    at myCode.main(file.java on line ?)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at myCode._invoke(file.java on line ?)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30
    at _runppnqw.equalPairOfBits(file.java on line 18)
```

Comment: What does your debugger tell you? Does the error occur before or after the first 2 loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is here

`int mLen = theN.length();`

should use `theM`

if the length of `theM` String is smaller than `theN` you will get the index out of bounds exception when you iterate past the length of theM string

Comment: Good Catch - Thanks - but got the same issue.... I can't believe I missed that though... I am adding the error that is being thrown

Comment: Actually, I see where you were going... I had to do an if statement to compare current lengths and then append the string that is shorter with an extra 0 to the front of it.  Now works perfectly.